# python - numpy loadtxt, define type for specific columns

Tags: python, numpy, types

I have a problem with python 3.x
It is known that Python3 reads byte strings as:`b'yourString'`

My problem is that I want to read a text file, comma separated with four columns that should be strings and the other are `int` or `float`

I know have:

```
data_files=np.genfromtxt(i, names=True, dtype=None, delimiter=",")
```

And I would like to do someting like (I know this does not work):

```
data_files=np.genfromtxt(i, names=True, dtype='None,str', delimiter=",",usecols=(0,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22)(1,7,10,13))
```

I tried it with:

```
alttype = np.dtype('f','s2','i2','i2','f0','f0','f0','s1','f0','f0','s1','f0','f0','s1','f0','f0','f0','f0','f0','f0','f0','f0','f0')
```

But this is limited to four sets long. I can't read them all as `str` since I do operations on the numbers afterwards

Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a link on  (sample of) data, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: What's wrong with the original `dtype=None` result?  I don't understand this `four sets long` bit.  How about two `genfromtxt` loads, one for the string columns, one for the numeric ones?

Comment: Hello B. M I'm sorry but I cannot provide this data :/
@hpaulj, I would love to be able to do that and then merge them but I get `TypeError: invalid type promotion`

Answer (score 0):

```
In [365]: alttype = np.dtype('f','s2','i2','i2','f0','f0','f0','s1','f0','f0','s1','f0','f0','s1','f0','f0','f0','f0','f0','f0','f0','f0','f0')
...
TypeError: function takes at most 4 arguments (23 given)
```

Arguments for `dtype` can have several forms, a string, a list of tuples, several dictionaries.  It's objecting to the nature of the arguments, not the number of fields that you try to define.  Also the `dtype` for `genfromtxt` is more flexible.  This format is used quite often: `dtype="i8,f8,S5"`

So an `alttype = 'f,S2,i,i,f,f,f,S1,...'` might work.  Don't use `f0`.

define a small sample 'file' (`genfromtxt` accepts a list of lines):

```
In [382]: txt=b"""A B C D E F G
     ...: a 23 2.1 c 2 3 7
     ...: b 22 2.0 d 2 5 8
     ...: """
```

Default load:

```
In [384]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),names=True,dtype=None)
Out[384]: 
array([(b'a', 23,  2.1, b'c', 2, 3, 7), 
       (b'b', 22,  2. , b'd', 2, 5, 8)], 
      dtype=[('A', 'S1'), ('B', '<i4'), ('C', '<f8'), ('D', 'S1'), ('E', '<i4'), ('F', '<i4'), ('G', '<i4')])
```

load just the string columns

```
In [385]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),names=True,dtype=None, usecols=[0,3])
Out[385]: 
array([(b'a', b'c'), (b'b', b'd')], 
      dtype=[('A', 'S1'), ('D', 'S1')])
```

spell out dtype for selected columns

```
In [387]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),names=True,dtype='U3,U3,i2,f4', usecols=[0,3,1,2])
Out[387]: 
array([('a', 'c', 23,  2.0999999), 
       ('b', 'd', 22,  2.       )], 
      dtype=[('A', '<U3'), ('D', '<U3'), ('B', '<i2'), ('C', '<f4')])
```